# Update Jinja2 template variables

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, variables, jinja2

I am using appengine with Python and jinja2 template.

I encountered an issue during the process: I render a list of games with this code

```
self.templateValues = {}
self.templateValues['title'] = 'GalaStore'
self.templateValues['values'] = kw
gamesQuery = Game.all()
values = {'games' : gamesQuery.run()}
self.templateValues['gl'] = values
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(template)        
self.response.out.write(template.render(self.templateValues))
```

then I have some button-filters in my html, and everyone calls a different js function. The problem is: once I hit the filter "sort by alpha" and I call a python function "sortByAlpha" via js (via ajax), how can I update the template variables in runtime withouth calling the template.render() function again? That would cause the reloading of the entire page and I would like to avoid it.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your AJAX request would either need to return the `games` object list in JSON form, so the JavaScript could update the list in the browser, or you would have a template rendering *just* that part of the page, and have JavaScript swap out that piece with the HTML loaded from your server.

The latter can be made reusable; have both your main view *and* your AJAX handler use the same template, rendering *just the list of games* (no the whole page):

```
def rendered_games_list(self, sort_by=None):
    games_query = Game.all()
    if sort_by:
        # I winged this bit, you didn't specify the ORM used
        games_query = games_query.order_by(sort_by)
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(games_list_template)        
    return template.render(gl=games_query.run())
```

then use this part in your main view:

```
template_values = {
    'title': 'GalaStore',
    'values': kw,
    'games_list': self.rendered_games_list()
}
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(template)        
self.response.out.write(template.render(self.templateValues))
```

and in your main template insert the rendered games list HTML as:

```
{{ games_list|safe }}
```

So your main template doesn't render the games list itself, it merely includes it.

Your AJAX handler can return the `rendered_games_list()` directly:

```
sort_order = self.request.get('sort_order', None)
self.response.out.write(self.rendered_games_list(sort_order))
```

Comment: Thanks!!But I have a doubt: using template.render the page will loag another time... or I did misunderstood?

Comment: @user2961930: you'll render *just that part* of the page. That's the idea.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work...... it doesn't render that part of template, it just prints it on response tab (in google chrome analyze page)..

Comment: @user2961930: You do need to code up the javascript on the client side to insert that HTML chunk into the page; jQuery has a [`.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that perhaps can help. Why it doesn't work in your case is impossible to tell from where I am standing. Perhaps you need to post a new question about that issue?

Comment: Done, thank you very much :) if you want you can help me with another problem, a bit simpler xD